# Pebble AppMessage JS json/csv -> C

Tags: c, csv, pebble-sdk

I'm experimenting with the Pebble SDK and would like to read solar data from the web.
I've managed to build an application completely in JS. See this [link](https://github.com/Sprk-nl/pebble.js_GoodWe).
[image]

As I found some limitations in JS, I'm rewriting the code in C.
When receiving json data via JS, I send this via a dictionary to C.
You can find the C version [here](https://github.com/Sprk-nl/Pebble.C_GoodWe)

**The RAW data received from the web:**

> [ { HourNum: "0:0", HourPower: "0" }, { HourNum: "0:10", HourPower:
>   "0" }, { HourNum: "0:20", HourPower: "0" }, etc

**The "HourPower" data filtered and send to C via the Dictonary option:**

> [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,59,72,89,110,127,160,192,253,316,352,360,522,539,601,598,770,582,650,810,741,805,894,908,864,904,962,1016,1106,1853,1503,1311,1406,1444,1401,1409,1344,1622,1472,1382,1609,1766,3310,3093,2041,1496,2068,3302,3185,1358,2760,2715,1285,994,1086,832,871,813,1707,1218,1218,239,203,170,132,70,53,45,39,39,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

**Two challenges:**

- 1 I wonder if I have received all the 144 entries.

In the logging I only see:

> Received buffer_solarvalue:
>   [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, <-stops here

Is the data between JS and C limited?
Do I need to split the data into multiple parts before sending them from JS to C?

- 2 I don't know how to process the data received in C.**
  I've read and tried several possibilities, trying to read native json and now trying to read it via csv, but How?

The final goal is to read these values from the web and create a graph.
But first I need to read the values properly in C.

Am I correct I should go the csv way?
Anyone with experience of a "larger" dataset between JS and C?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't use strtok in CloudPebble so I wrote this function to advance a pointer to the next number

```
void skip_over_char(char **buffer, const char lookup) {
  while(((*buffer)[0] != lookup) && ((*buffer)[0] != '\0')) {
    (*buffer)++;
  }
  (*buffer)++; //skip over lookup character
}
```

Then you can add the values to the solar_values array in this way. As a result you can see that you do indeed receive all 144 entries.

```
static int solar_values[144];
static int index;
static int received;
char *pch;

case KEY_SOLARVALUE :
  received = snprintf(buffer_solarvalue, sizeof(buffer_solarvalue), "%s", t->value->cstring);
  APP_LOG(APP_LOG_LEVEL_INFO , "Received buffer_solarvalue: %s", buffer_solarvalue);
  pch = buffer_solarvalue;
  skip_over_char(&pch, '[');
  index = 0;
  while (pch - buffer_solarvalue < received) {
    solar_values[index++] = atoi(pch);
    APP_LOG(APP_LOG_LEVEL_INFO, "solar_values[%3d] = %d", index - 1, solar_values[index-1]);
    skip_over_char(&pch, ',');
  }
  APP_LOG(APP_LOG_LEVEL_INFO , "Received %d values", index);
  break;
```

Comment: Thank you both for pointing me to what seems a logical direction.
I've also tested how many entries one dictionary entry can hold.
The answer I come up with is 58 characters, like:
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

If I want to send data like nr: 1000 or 2000, I only can send ± 9 data entries, which makes the total of 16 dictionary entries.

As 16 entries makes no sense, I need to find a way to send the data in parts: send data batch1, wait for acknowledge, send the next batch.

It's a great learning step in C and the Pebble way of work.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you have to do if you want to read `144` values, is send `144` values for conversion. Your data contains only `138`:

> [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,59,72,89,110,127,160,192,253,316,352,360,522,539,601,598,770,582,650,810,741,805,894,908,864,904,962,1016,1106,1853,1503,1311,1406,1444,1401,1409,1344,1622,1472,1382,1609,1766,3310,3093,2041,1496,2068,3302,3185,1358,2760,2715,1285,994,1086,832,871,813,1707,1218,1218,239,203,170,132,70,53,45,39,39,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

You have many choices for converting the csv data to numbers. `strtok`, `strsep`, or personally my choice `strtol`. The reason being is that for numerical conversion, `strtol` (and it sister functions) provide the greatest degree of error reporting on conversion failure.

Since `strtol (const char *nptr, char **endptr, int base);` makes use of a pointer to the digits to be converted (`nptr`) and updates an ending pointer (`endptr`) that points to the next character following the number just converted, it is ideal for walking down a string of digits separated by *any* delimiter and coverting all values to numbers.

The following is just a quick example of how you might make use of it converting your **"HourPower" data** to individual integers contained within an array. For purposes of the example, your values are simply read from `stdin`. I have provided loose error checking just to catch some of the basic errors that would otherwise lead to writing beyond the end of your array, etc. They are examples of error checks, not intended to be exhaustive.

Look it over and let me know if you have questions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define NDATA 160
#define MAXC 1024

long xstrtol (char *p, char **ep, int base);

int main (void) {

    char line[MAXC] = {0};              /* line buffer for fgets    */
    char *p, *ep;                       /* pointers for strtol      */
    int array[NDATA] = {0};             /* array of values          */
    size_t idx = 0, nelem = 0;          /* indexes, number of ints  */

    /* read each line in file */
    while (fgets(line, MAXC, stdin))
    {
        p = ep = line;  /* initize pointer/end pointer      */

        /* convert each csv value to number, store in array */
        while (errno == 0)
        {
            /* skip delimiters/move pointer to next digit */
            while (*ep && *ep != '-' && (*ep < '0' || *ep > '9')) ep++;
            if (*ep)
                p = ep;
            else  /* break if end of string */
                break;

            array[idx++] = (int)xstrtol (p, &ep, 10); /* convert */

            if (idx == NDATA) { /* NDATA reached, conversion error */
                fprintf (stderr, "error: conversion exceeded 144.\n");
                return 1;
            }

        }

        if (idx != 144)   /* validate 144 values converted */
            fprintf (stderr, "warning: invalid conversion of '%zu' values.\n",
                    idx);

        nelem = idx;  /* save the final number of values (144) */
    }

    printf ("\n the converted json values are:\n\n");
    for (idx = 0; idx < nelem; idx++) {
        printf ("  array[%2zu] : %d\n", idx, array[idx]);
    }
    putchar ('\n');

    return 0;
}

/** a simple strtol implementation with error checking.
*  any failed conversion will cause program exit. Adjust
*  response to failed conversion as required.
*/
long xstrtol (char *p, char **ep, int base)
{
    errno = 0;

    long tmp = strtol (p, ep, base);

    /* Check for various possible errors */
    if ((errno == ERANGE && (tmp == LONG_MIN || tmp == LONG_MAX)) ||
        (errno != 0 && tmp == 0)) {
        perror ("strtol");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (*ep == p) {
        fprintf (stderr, "No digits were found\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return tmp;
}
```

**Example Output**

```
$ ./bin/array_json_xstrtol <hpdata.txt
warning: invalid conversion of '138' values.

 the converted json values are:

  array[ 0] : 0
  array[ 1] : 0
  array[ 2] : 0
  array[ 3] : 0
  array[ 4] : 0
  array[ 5] : 0
  array[ 6] : 0
  array[ 7] : 0
  array[ 8] : 0
  array[ 9] : 0
  array[10] : 0
...
  array[47] : 59
  array[48] : 72
  array[49] : 89
  array[50] : 110
  array[51] : 127
  array[52] : 160
  array[53] : 192
  array[54] : 253
  array[55] : 316
  array[56] : 352
  array[57] : 360
  array[58] : 522
  array[59] : 539
...
  array[130] : 0
  array[131] : 0
  array[132] : 0
  array[133] : 0
  array[134] : 0
  array[135] : 0
  array[136] : 0
  array[137] : 0
```

Where `hpdata.txt` contained your example data.

Comment: You are right about only 138. 
The solar data can grow for a whole day to 144. (each 10 minutes of 24 hours). Thank you for your extended answer!

Comment: Sure glad to help. Hopefully, you can make use of some of it. I've done a lot of work with data parsing/numerical conversions and this is about the most flexible and robust way to approach it. If you use `strtok` or `strsep`, all they do is separate the values, you still have to go through the process of converting the strings to numbers -- this does it all in one shot, using `endptr` the way it was intended...